# c-lightning - Failed to replicate query: database disk image is malformed

Tags: core-lightning

When I start up lightningd with `sudo systemctl start lightningd`, no error is returned.

When I run `sudo journalctl -f -u lightningd`, I get this:

```
$ sudo journalctl -f -u lightningd
-- Journal begins at Tue 2023-01-31 10:49:40 EET. --
Feb 11 14:24:44 raspibolt systemd[1]: Started Core Lightning daemon.
Feb 11 14:25:54 raspibolt sh[184030]: Failed to replicate query: database disk image is malformed: database disk image is malformed: DELETE FROM blocks WHERE height > 775495
Feb 11 14:25:54 raspibolt systemd[1]: lightningd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 11 14:25:54 raspibolt systemd[1]: lightningd.service: Killing process 184047 (node) with signal SIGKILL.
Feb 11 14:25:54 raspibolt systemd[1]: lightningd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 11 14:25:54 raspibolt systemd[1]: lightningd.service: Consumed 3.860s CPU time.
Feb 11 14:26:24 raspibolt systemd[1]: lightningd.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3417.
Feb 11 14:26:24 raspibolt systemd[1]: Stopped Core Lightning daemon.
Feb 11 14:26:24 raspibolt systemd[1]: lightningd.service: Consumed 3.860s CPU time.
Feb 11 14:26:24 raspibolt systemd[1]: Started Core Lightning daemon.
```

Lightning daemon isn't running:

```
$ lightning-cli getinfo
lightning-cli: Connecting to 'lightning-rpc': Connection refused
```

Do you know what's the fault?

Extra information that might be helpful: Verification progress is 99.9993% in my Bitcoin node.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your database is malformed and it has some corrupted data inside the database, it is not directly related to the bitcoin node!

However, I think it is good to report the issue to https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning/issues